# Fill missing data based on the other columns same data

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

The data like below:

```
index  Column A    Column B       Column C   
  0       a           1             NaN  
  1       b           1             12
  2       a           1             11
  3       c           2              5
  4       d           3              7
  5       b           2             NaN
```

I want to fill the Column C missing data by the same key in Column A and Column B, 
the output I want is:

```
index  Column A    Column B       Column C   
  0       a           1             11  
  1       b           1             12
  2       a           1             11
  3       c           2              5
  4       d           3              7
  5       b           2             NaN
```

How I can get this result?
Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby(['Column A', 'Column B'])['Column C'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Comment: Not clear, could you please put more details on this question @Starry

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the first answer works, thank you for your reply

Comment: @user3483203, thanks for sharing this code, I am new to pandas could you please explain it a bit, will be grateful to you(I didn't understand question also fully to be honest that is why asked OP for clarifications).